# Can't Create Blob Container: This request is not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-python-sdk

I'm trying to create a blob container within an Azure storage account with Azure's Python API.

```py
def create_storage_container(storageAccountName: str, containerName: str):
    print(
        f"Creating storage container '{containerName}'",
        f"in storage account '{storageAccountName}'"
    )
    credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
    url = f"https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net"
    blobClient = BlobServiceClient(account_url=url, credential=credentials)
    containerClient = blobClient.get_container_client(containerName)
    containerClient.create_container()
```

On `create_container()` I get the error:

```py
Exception has occurred: HttpResponseError
This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:8a3f8af1-101e-0075-3351-074949000000
Time:2022-12-03T20:00:25.5236364Z
ErrorCode:AuthorizationFailure
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationFailure</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:8a3f8af1-101e-0075-3351-074949000000
Time:2022-12-03T20:00:25.5236364Z</Message></Error>
```

The storage account was created like so:

```py
# Creates a storage account if it does not already exist.
# Returns the name of the storage account.
def create_storage_account(
    resourceGroupName: str, location: str,
    subscriptionId: str, storageAccountName: str
):

    credentials = AzureCliCredential()

    # Why does this have creation powers for storage accounts
    # instead of the ResourceManagementClient?
    storageClient = StorageManagementClient(
        credentials, subscriptionId, "2018-02-01"
    )
    params = {
        "sku": {"name": "Standard_LRS", "tier": "Standard"},
        "kind": "StorageV2",
        "location": location,
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": True,
    }

    result = storageClient.storage_accounts.begin_create(
        resourceGroupName, storageAccountName, params
    )  # type:ignore
    storageAccount = result.result(120)
    print(f"Done creating storage account with name: {storageAccount.name}")
```

The storage accounts that are generated like this seem to have completely open network access, so I wouldn't think that would be an issue.

Storage account network settings:

[image]

How can I fix this error or create a storage container in another way programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got same error in results:**

**Console:**

[image]

If you are accessing storage account you need a role like **[Storage-blob-contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal)** or **storage-blob-owner**.

Go to portal -> storage accounts -> Access Control (IAM) ->Add -> Add role assignments -> storage-blob-contributor or storage-blob-owner.

**Portal:**

[image]

*After assigning role to my storage account, I executed same code and it successfully created container.*

**Code:**

```py
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient
from  azure.identity  import  DefaultAzureCredential

storageAccountName="venkat123"
containerName="test"

def create_storage_container():
    print(
        f"Creating storage container '{containerName}'",
        f"in storage account '{storageAccountName}'"
    )
    credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
    url = f"https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net"
    blobClient = BlobServiceClient(account_url=url, credential=credentials)
    containerClient = blobClient.get_container_client(containerName)
    containerClient.create_container()
    print("Container created")
create_storage_container()
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the RBAC roles your user is assigned to for the storage account. The default ones don’t always enable you to view data and sounds like it’s causing your problems.

Comment: How do you check the RBAC roles? I would assume that since I create the storage account in the same script where I try to create the container that I would have all permissions to that storage account.... Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm pretty new to Azure in general.

Comment: You can check them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/check-access#step-2-check-access-for-a-user) in the Azure portal.

Comment: I can also see that you use both DefaultAzureCredential and AzureCliCredential, is there any reason for that? The DefaultAzureCredential will pick the available credentials in a certain order until it finds something that works or otherwise throw an error. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet). 

Have you checked that it actually receives any credentials here?